# getElementByClassName without divs

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I need some advice.

Lets see, I have html code like this:

```
<body>
    <span class="example">Example Text</span>
    <span class="notthis">Other Text</span>
</body>
```

Yes, there is no div! How can I repalce text between span with class="example" ?

I tried:

```
var elem = document.getElementByClassName("example");
elem.innerHTML = "change example text to something other";
```

But it does not work, of course if there would be div and take getElementById and then ClassName, it works perfectly.

Problem is that there is no div :)

Is it even possible?

Regards,

Tagon

Comment: There really is no div! Yes! :)

Comment: Spans are elements too :-)

Comment: I bet you have an error message like `getElementByClassName is not a function` or `undefined is not a function` as it should be `getElementsByClassName` with a `s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this problem doesn't relate with the `div` or `span`

`getElementById` selects the first element of given id,
`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

**use `getElementsByClassName` in place of `getElementByClassName`.**

*you want to put innerHTML to the first element of a class `example`*,so try the below code

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0];
elem.innerHTML = "change example text to something other";
```

Comment: Also it's `getElement**s**ByClassName`.

Answer (score 2):

*getElementsByClassName("example")* would return a HTMLCollection with the first span with class ="example" in it, so change to:

> var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("example"); 
>   elem[0].innerHTML = "change example text to something other";

You can read Specification about getElementsByClassName():  [W3C](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname)

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your code:

1:
It's `getElementsByClassName` and not `getElementByClassName`.

2: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of nodes and not one node. So if you want to change the text on all the matching elements you will have to loop through the elements:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var elem = elements[i];
    elem.innerHTML = "change example text to something other";
}
```

But if you only want to change the text on the first matching element you can do this:

```
var elem = document.getElementByClassName("example")[0];
elem.innerHTML = "change example text to something other";
```

Note: `getElementsByClassName` will work on any element even if there is no div

Answer (score 0):

[getElementByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns array-like objects, so, change to:

```
var elem = document.getElementByClassName("example");
elem[0].innerHTML = "change example text to something other";
```